# Three20 Issues with Build and Archive on XCode 4

Tags: ios, xcode4, three20

I have ported an existing Three20 xcode 3.2 project to xcode 4 using the [tutorial](http://three20.info/article/2011-03-10-Xcode4-Support)

The code compiles and runs on the device. Now, I am trying to build an ipa (using the archive command) and am running into similar errors as this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261447/xcode-4-three20-create-ipa-archive-no-such-file-or-directory)

The error is:

`cd: /Users/[username]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pulse_News-cnosepsavjismxbmhuvmmvxnnpgh/ArchiveIntermediates/Pulse News/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/../three20/Three20Core: No such file or directory`

Unfortunately, neither the tutorial nor the post have helped much. Is there something I am missing? Is funny that I am able to build the project and run it fine, but not able to build an archive! Please help.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the "No such file or directory" error message is correct. Considering this, the answer to your question depends on your providing more information about how you have project dependencies and search paths configured in your project.

For self-help, take a careful look at the path it's saying doesn't exist and see if you can figure out why. Note projects within the same *workspace* share build paths; if you're not using a workspace, you'll need to verify the search paths point to the build location of the other (three20) project.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the first of your problems. When you upgrade a three20 xcode 3.2 project to 4, you will probably also get an invalid binary message when you upload to itunes.

The only solution that worked for me was to create a new project, re-add all the source files and run the three20 python script with something like:

python /Users/yourpath/three20/src/scripts/ttmodule.py -p /Users/yourpath/YourProject.xcodeproj Three20 extThree20JSON:extThree20JSON+SBJSON --xcode-version=4 -c Debug -c Release

It's a pain to have to do this but it will probably save you more pain down the line