# XCode header files scanning issue

Tags: xcode4, route-me

I'm working with Xcode4 and Route-me project.

I'm creating my project and including dependencies on RouteMe like the
"Embedding guide" explains (https://github.com/route-me/route-me/wiki/Embedding-Guide).

The problem is XCode4 isn't able to autocomplete RouteMe names. Momentarily
in the *.h or *.m I can write "RMMa" and editor suggests me
"RMMapView" but later it never appears again.
It seems like the files scanning for later autocompleting fails.

Anybody has suffer the same issues like me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try [step 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584317/lexical-or-preprocessor-issue-file-not-found-in-xcode-4/5607376#5607376) of this answer: [“lexical or preprocessor issue file not found ” in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584317/lexical-or-preprocessor-issue-file-not-found-in-xcode-4)

> 3 - Create a group call "Indexing headers" in your project and drag the
>   headers to this group, DO NOT add to
>   any targets when prompted.

Comment: Code sense and code completion doesn't work. I remove the derived data folder (using organizer) but not works.

Comment: I found this which can help: http://acuriousanimal.com/blog/2011/05/06/xcode4-and-the-mystery-with-route-me-code-sense/