# Managing libraries in Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, xcode4

I'm currently trying to import the [facebook-ios-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) into one of my projects.
My approach is to import my project and the project of the facebook-ios-sdk into one workspace, but my project can't find the header files of the facebook sdk. I thought that the files in one workspace will be shared isn't it? How can I import the facebook-ios-sdk to my project without copying the files directly into my project?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope to understand what you want. I'm using facebook-ios-sdk, and I added all files in directoctory src (.m and .h) in my project with right click, "add files to…"[image: Project screenshot]

Comment: this is the way according to the readme on github, but I manage the facebook sdk as a submodule in GIT and if new files will be added, Xcode cant recognize that, isn't it?

Comment: White font on a black background. You must be missing the VT220 and 3270 terminals badly...

Comment: @Codo White font on a black background is so soothing no ?…

Answer (score 0):

Try [step 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584317/lexical-or-preprocessor-issue-file-not-found-in-xcode-4/5607376#5607376) of this answer: [“lexical or preprocessor issue file not found ” in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584317/lexical-or-preprocessor-issue-file-not-found-in-xcode-4)

> 3 - Create a group call "Indexing headers" in your project and drag the
>   headers to this group, DO NOT add to
>   any targets when prompted.

Comment: I want to be independent from the imported framework. So I think just adding the headers would not be the best way