# Lexical or Preprocessor Issue error causing Core data class "may not respond to" method warnings?

Tags: iphone

I get `Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'Group.h' file not found` which I believe is causing the issues below.

I'm trying to call a method on one of my core data class instances and I get a `'Group' may not respond to '-addPeople:'` warning. But I do have an addPeople method in my XCode generated Group class, and here it is:

```
- (void)addPeople:(NSSet *)value {    
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"people" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:value];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"people"] unionSet:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"people" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:value];
}
```

I also get the same warning if I try to `removePeople`. Both of these methods have to do with NSSets but I'm able to call my setters from the Group class just fine.

```
[selectedObject setTitle:[[titleCell textField] text]]; // works
[selectedObject setSubtitle:[[subTitleCell textField] text]]; // works
NSSet *tempPeople = [NSSet setWithArray:people];
[selectedObject addPeople:tempPeople]; // works, but with warning
```

**Side note**

When I type `[selectedObject` I don't get autocompletion, although the word selectedObject does autocomplete as a Group. So at least that's good.

**Group.h**

```
@class People;

@interface Group : NSManagedObject {
@private
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * order;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * subtitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet* people;
@end
```

**Updated**

I just finished making a new UITableViewCell class and now instead of it saying `Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'Group.h' file not found` it now says `Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'PersonCell.h' file not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Lexical or Preprocessor Issue**

Well, I couldn't figure out what my problem was so I made a new project and remade each view controller, core data and whatever else I needed. And that solved my problem. I wish I knew what was really causing the Lexical error but from the looks of other people's posts, it could have been a bug.

**Group' may not respond to '-addPeople:**

This issue was resolved by adding the methods to the .h file. I'm not sure why XCode didn't make those for me, but that solved that problem.

And thanks **xianritchie** for trying to figure this out with me. It was appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you were able to post your interface file as well. These are a few reasons I might see for this:

You HAVE a Group.h file, but it does not have a method declaration for these methods.
You HAVE a Group.h file, it does have method declarations, but you are not #importing the Group.h into the other class.
You do NOT have a Group.h file at all, and are attempting to configure the method and variables as private objects in the implementation file.

Can you post more of your code for us? Possibly the [selectedObject] declaration as well?

Comment: Well, assuming that you are properly importing Group.h into your other class, AND assuming you have closed XCode completely and the iOS simulator and restarted, I would recommend removing Group.h from your application (but do not delete it), and then re-adding it.

Comment: Take a look at this thread. It has some insightful information as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584317/compile-build-or-archive-problems-with-xcode-4-and-dependancies?tab=active

Comment: I read that and I couldn't figure out what "user header paths" was or anything else he was talking about. I'm still trying to decipher it.