# including C/C++ headers in Xcode 4

Tags: c++, c, xcode4, header, string.h

I've been using a C++ library without problems on projects built with Xcode 3, but I'm now getting build problems on projects built with Xcode 4.

Drop the library into the Xcode 4 project and it builds fine, but as soon as I `#include` it, I get a "Lexical or Preprocessor Issue" error, more specifically " 'string' file not found, on line 4 of its main header file.

On closer inspection, the error specifies that `'string' file not found in ~/my project's directory/include/mainheader.h`

I've tried the solutions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584317/compile-build-or-archive-problems-with-xcode-4-and-dependancies), but none worked.

So it thinks that header file is in my project directory, but it's obviously a C/C++ header… How can I tell Xcode to look for these C/C++ headers?

Comment: Are you using `#include "string.h"` or `#include <string.h>`?There is a difference.

Comment: the library uses `#include <string>`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `#include <string.h>`? I've never heard of just including a file called "string" in c++

Comment: That's legal, it's a class template (see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/)), Xcode 3 didn't see it as a problem, so this has got something to do with Xcode 4.

Comment: Try Checking your build phases & settings, & make sure that the file is compiling as C++ and not C.

Comment: I checked, that problematic header file has "C++ header" as File Type.

Comment: @Eric:  but what about all the files it is included in?  They must all be C++ or Objective-C++

Comment: I do that `#include` in my main header file, which is a C header. I'm still getting that problem when I set its file type as "C++ header".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problematic `#include` was at the top of my `ViewController.mm`, which I had already turned into Objective-C++ by giving it `.mm` as its extension. But `ViewController.mm` gets eventually imported by `AppDelegate.m`, which is Objective-C by default – and I had forgotten to make it Objective-C++, hence the problem.

So renaming `AppDelegate.m` to `AppDelegate.mm` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think #include  is a c++ class template..so you need to used using namespace std in your header file and also rename your source file .m format to .mm format.

it works for me :) try this...

Comment: I'm not familiar with xCode and OSX/iOS development, but this statement - *#include is a c++ class template* - is definitely not correct.

Comment: The C++ Standard Template Library (STL) contains a string class that is used in several computer science classes.
Check this :: http://www.bgsu.edu/departments/compsci/docs/string.html
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: Thanks, but none of your links shows the explanation. This page has it at the very end: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/

Comment: Putting `using namespace ANYTHING;` in a header is not a good idea. There is no point having namespaces in that case.

Comment: @saif Your solution (renaming the source file) is probably correct, but the answer is a bit confusing. `std::string` is not a template, but it is a class. I think you might mean "class declaration". `#include` is a way to read other files, regardless of their contents.