# Cannot include boost libraries in Ogre iPhone SDK version

Tags: iphone, xcode4, ogre3d, ogre

I installed the Ogre3D iPhone SDK and tried to compile the sample project in XCode4. I ran into "lexical or preprocessor issue" which many people have been experiencing in XCode4. In my case, XCode was not able to fine "OgreCamera.h".

I managed to solve this problem by creating an "Indexing" group folder in my project and dragging the header files into it as suggested in this thread:

[Compile, Build or Archive problems with Xcode 4 (and dependencies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584317/compile-build-or-archive-problems-with-xcode-4-and-dependancies)

However, I ran into the same issue again in a different form. There are no more errors about "OgreCamera.h", but now  I'm getting "'boost/thread/tss.hpp' file not found". I've dragged the boost folder and the individual boost header files into the Indexing group, to no effect.

All my include paths are configured correctly, XCode should be able to find these files based on my build settings.

I don't know what to do. I've searched for solutions to this and failed to find any. My best guess is that the contents of the Indexing group need to be a flat hierarchy with no sub folders, but Ogre references the boost headers files using a file path: "boost/thread/tss.hpp", and this causes problems for some reason. But I don't know how to go about fixing it.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was copying boost into the root of the OgreSDK and then adding the following to my header search paths

```
$(SRCROOT)/boost
```

You'll notice the file being included is "boost/thread/tss.hpp".  So using the above header search path it would be looking for `$(SRCROOT)/boost/boost/thread/tss.hpp`.

Assuming you have `$SRCROOT/include` in your header search paths - the solution is just to move the boost folder to your include directory.

PS... if you don't have a boost folder you'll need to download boost and copy it in there.