# Cannot find <opencv2/opencv.hpp> under XCode 4.4 OS10.8

Tags: boost, opencv, homebrew, osx-mountain-lion, xcode4.4

I just updated my Mac OS to Mountain Lion, and also the XCode to version 4.4.

However after updating I can no longer build any of my codes. XCode keeps complaining that

```
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue
opencv2/opencv.hpp file not found
```

For every single #include  It was working perfectly okay the day before. It also complains the same issue for #include .

FYI: I had my boost and opencv libraries installed thru Homebrew.

Does anyone else have the same issue, or does anyone have any idea how to resolve these issues ?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584317/compile-build-or-archive-problems-with-xcode-4-and-dependancies

Answer (score 0):

system python may require updating/reinstall homebrew and reinstalling all your packages. I chose to do so, and it corrected all the errors I was running into