# iOS: Archive fails

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I'm trying to distribute my iOS app. I'm trying to build the archive. The app runs fine, but when I try to archive it, it tells me it can't find ".h" files that it no problem finding for Build > Run.

They are ".h" files from different projects and libraries I have included in my project.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never come across this problem when archiving, but what I can offer to you is to take a look at the accepted answer in the following thread to see if it helps you resolve the issue you are experiencing:  [Compile, Build or Archive problems with Xcode 4 (and dependencies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584317/compile-build-or-archive-problems-with-xcode-4-and-dependancies)