# Restkit 0.20: not found when building archive inside own static library

Tags: xcode4, static-libraries, archive, restkit-0.20

I created my own framework, which itself depends on the RestKit framework.

I created an App which uses my framework, and I added to the app the RestKit framework as described by their tutorial.

I use the latest version 0.20.2 and if I build it in Xcode (either simulator or to the device) all works fine.

As soon as I want to create an archive it can't find the `<RestKit/RestKit.h>` header anymore.

How do I need to adapt the `Header Search Paths` so it will find the RestKit even when building for an archive? (at the moment my framework only contains `"$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../Headers"`)

I already tried [This solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584317/compile-build-or-archive-problems-with-xcode-4-and-dependancies) but unfortunately without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your release configuration, specify a recursive search path of:

```
"$(BUILD_ROOT)/../"
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually added '"$(SRCROOT)/Build/Headers"' and this was enough, but the BUILD_ROOT i didn't figure out.