# Lexical or preprocessor issue: CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a readymade project in iOS which includes various frameworks like: `MapKit` , `SDWebImage`, `CoreLocation` , etc.
When i try to run the project i get error:

```
Lexical or preprocessor issue: CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h not found
```

But `CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h` is present. I deleted and again added the `mapkit` and `corelocation` frameworks. Still i get the same error.
I also cleaned and built the project- same error.
I even deleted the workspace and reopened it  by referring this link :[Compile, Build or Archive problems with Xcode 4 (and dependencies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584317/compile-build-or-archive-problems-with-xcode-4-and-dependencies)

Still the same error.

How do i solve this? Any solutions are welcomed.

Comment: Can you post the code where you import CoreLocation.h?

Comment: if you are 100% sure that you have imported the CoreLocation framework... How do you import the framework's headers? #import "CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h", or #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h> ?

Comment: What are your framework search paths from build settings?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on Xcode 5, use `@import CoreLocation` instead of #import. This takes advantage of the [new modules feature in LLVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947516/import-vs-import-ios-7) to import the headers AND link against the framework for you.